# Clustering and differentially expressed genes in RNAseq

Tags: r, sequence-analysis

I have performed differential analysis with DESeq2, edgeR and voom-limma. My goal was to evaluate each methods on my data.
Now I would like to perform clustering with the genes found differentially expressed (DEG) by each method to see how well these genes discriminat my two conditions. To do so, I have to shoot my counts through some type of variance stabilizing transformation

Should I do all my clusterings with rlog data and the 3 sets of DEG ?

I wonder if it is relevant to do a clustering with DEG from voom on data that have been transform with rlog or with DEG from DESeq2 on data that have been transform by voom ?

Any clues ?
Thanks

Comment: These are all bioconductor methods, so you should really ask on their support site: https://support.bioconductor.org/